# Can I use multipule DHT22's reading seperate temp/ humidity on a mega2560?

Tags: c++, android-layout, arduino, android-sensors

ok, I have been building a tissue culture lab. It has three compartments, one is for new culture, second is for vegetating plants and third for full grown plants. I have two Arduino mega boards one is already setup to monitor the lights and temp and controls 4 relays on a 8 channel board. I have three Dht22 for the second mega board but I have no clue how to make them work the way I want to. I would like each to read and report one for each compartment - so I can control airflow based on humidity through ventilation. How can I make three dht22 work and read separately? Any help with code is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, is there something you have already tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply creating multiple dht objects and polling them separately?

```
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPINA 2     // what digital pin the first one's connected to
#define DHTPINB 3     // what digital pin the second one's connected to

#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302), AM2321

DHT dhtA(DHTPINA, DHTTYPE);
DHT dhtB(DHTPINA, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("DHTxx test!");

  dhtA.begin();
  dhtB.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(2000);
  float tA = dhtA.readTemperature();
  float tB = dhtB.readTemperature();

  Serial.print("Temp A:")
  Serial.print(tA)
  Serial.print("Temp B:")
  Serial.print(tB)
}
```

adapted from [this](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino).

Comment: *note this is slightly outside my expertise, and I don't have an arduino to test with..